# Display a Loading icon while images loads

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I want to show a background image/loading spinner inside a `div` that will load an image inside of it, the image will show once it's fully loaded doing something like this:

```
   <div style="background-image:url('imageThatWillAppearBeforeLoad')"></div>
```

[Demo (In jQuery)](http://smallenvelop.com/demo/image-loading/)

How can I have the same using Angular2/Ionic2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 : (Lazy) Loading spinner for pictures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846271/ionic-2-lazy-loading-spinner-for-pictures)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a component that shows the placeholder image until the requested image is loaded, and hides the requested image. Once the image is loaded, you hide the placeholder and show the image.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'image-loader',
  template: `<img *ngIf="!loaded" src="url-to-your-placeholder"/>
    <img [hidden]="!loaded" (load)="loaded = true" [src]="src"/>`
})
export class ImageLoader {
  @Input() src;
}
```

See it working in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/piyHj74UH102c7oVhVOe).

**Update**

Now that I understand the requirements better, here's a solution with background image. It's a little hacky, and I like the original one better...

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[imageLoader]'
})
export class ImageLoader {
  @Input() imageLoader;

  constructor(private el:ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
    this.el.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://smallenvelop.com/demo/image-loading/spinner.gif)";
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${this.imageLoader})`;
    });
    image.src = this.imageLoader;
  }
}
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yoh6035xZHEWdpiIMEJU?p=preview).

Comment: Your code is working fine, but for my case as I've posted, I've a `<div style="background-image:url('imageThatWillAppearBeforeLoad')"></div>` that contains an image in background, I've tried to tweak your code to match the `div` I have but It didn't worked, Is it possible to make it work as a `div` ?

Comment: For what I achieved so far I guess that (load) does not work for some reason! Because I've replaced the `img` with `div`, etc... when I go to check the `DOM`, I see hidden which means that loaded = true was not applied for some reason, what makes me even sure that there is an issue with `(load)` is that I replace it with `(click)` then I place it in the placeholder `div` and it worked!
So, do you have any idea why `(load)` didn't worked?

Comment: It didn't work because `div`s don't have an `onload` event... This is why I made the component that way.

Comment: Does it have to be a `div`? Do you need the requested image also as a background-image, or can that be a `img` element?

Comment: It needs to be a `div` not `img`

Comment: that's the thing I need it as `background-image`

Comment: it shows both, the loader and the image, check please the plunker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118139/discussion-between-yarons-and-folky-h).

Comment: I ended up switching to the `img` tag, now everything works well!! Thank you for all the efforts +1

Comment: How can we do this for Ionic 1?

Comment: While this solution works (updated version), the directive triggers 2 separate GET calls. After debugging I can confirm that both `this.el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${this.imageLoader})`;` and `image.src = this.imageLoader;` each trigger 1 call respectively. Is there any solution which prevents from sending the GET request for the image twice?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a copy of one of my [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846271/ionic-2-lazy-loading-spinner-for-pictures/38846370#38846370)

I finally solved that problem with CSS! When an image is loading in ionic 2, the ion-img tag doesn't have any class. However, when the image is finally loaded, the ion-img tag get the class "img-loaded".

Here is my solution :

```
  <ion-img [src]="img.src"></ion-img>
  <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
```

And my CSS :

```
.img-loaded + ion-spinner {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this function

```
loadImage(element: HTMLElement, imagePath: string, spinnerPath: string) {
  element.tagName === 'img'
    ? element.setAttribute('src', spinnerPath)
    : (element.style.background = `url(${spinnerPath}) 50% 50% no-repeat`);
  const image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  image.src = imagePath;
  image.onload = () => {
    element.tagName === 'img'
      ? element.setAttribute('src', imagePath)
      : (element.style.background = `url(${imagePath})`);
  };
}
```

You don't have to worry about your element is image or div or whatever it is?

example if you didn't figure out how to use it

```
ngOnInit() {
  const myElement = document.getElementsByClassName('my-element')[0];
  // or however you want to select it.
  const imagePath = 'path/to/image.png';
  const spinnerPath = 'path/to/spinner.gif'; // or base64 spinner url.

  this.loadImage(myElement, imagePath, spinnerPath);
}
```

Happy coding