# Ionic 2 / Ionic 3 / Ionic 4 : (Lazy) Loading spinner for pictures

Tags: mobile, angular, typescript, sass, ionic2

I'm using ion-img in my ionic2 application to load my pictures correctly. However, I wonder if there is a way to indicate to the user that the picture is actually loading.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT : Here is the answer if you absolutely need to use the ion-img tag. If not, you should use [ionic-image-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader) as [AdminDev826](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7762525/admindev826) suggested.**

I finally solved that problem with CSS! When an image is loading in ionic 2, the ion-img tag doesn't have any class. However, when the image is finally loaded, the ion-img tag get the class "img-loaded".

Here is my solution :

```
  <ion-img [src]="img.src"></ion-img>
  <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
```

And my CSS :

```
.img-loaded + ion-spinner {
  display:none;
}
```

I hope it can help someone!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please use ionic-image-loader plugin

1. Install the NPM Package

   ```
   npm install --save ionic-image-loader
   ```
2. Install Required Plugins

   ```
   npm i --save @ionic-native/file

   ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save

   npm i --save @ionic-native/transfer
   ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --save
   ```
3. Import IonicImageLoader module

   Add IonicImageLoader.forRoot() in your app's root module

   ```
   import { IonicImageLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

   // import the module
   @NgModule({
    ...
     imports: [
       IonicImageLoader.forRoot()
     ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```

   Then add IonicImageLoader in your child/shared module(s)

   ```
   import { IonicImageLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

   @NgModule({
   ...
     imports: [
       IonicImageLoader
     ]
   })
   export class SharedModule {}
   ```

Comment: Please check this link for more detail

Comment: I'm actually using it ;-)
Thank you for this new answer!

Comment: Hope you can accept this answer then no? @GuillaumeLeMière

Comment: This does not work with angular 5 - the image loader never disappears

Comment: I tried this with Ionic 3 and Angular 5 but it doesn't add any spinner

Comment: HI @AdminDev826 I am new in ionic can you please tell me where can I find my child/shared module(s)?. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 15):

I finally solved that problem with CSS! When an image is loading in ionic 2, the ion-img tag doesn't have any class. However, when the image is finally loaded, the ion-img tag get the class "img-loaded".

Here is my solution :

```
  <ion-img [src]="img.src"></ion-img>
  <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
```

And my CSS :

```
.img-loaded + ion-spinner {
  display:none;
}
```

I hope it can help someone!

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the `img` tag instead of `ion-img` here is the solution:

```
  <img src="{{image.src}}" (load)="loaded = true" [ngClass]="{'img-loaded':loaded}" [hidden]="!loaded" *ngIf="image_exists" />
  <ion-spinner [ngClass]="{'center':true}" *ngIf="!loaded"></ion-spinner>
```

In your CSS file you should write the following:

```
 .img-loaded + ion-spinner {
  display:none;
}
// .center in my case to make the spinner at the center
.center{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

`loaded` is a boolean variable with false default value you have to define in your component.

Comment: but you'd need to add a spinner for each image

Comment: This is actually a better way than using `ion-img` because `load` event in this method called when the image fully loaded, but in `ion-img` the `ionImgDidLoad` event called on setting the `src` attribute of image, not when the image fully loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is not the best one because the app still downloads all the images, For example in a Facebook like app, You will be downloading all the images from the Feed to your app, This will make everything super slow.

Use this:
https://github.com/NathanWalker/ng2-image-lazy-load

Comment: It depends on how you use that code. In a facebook style app, just use the following : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/

Comment: @Yossi Neiman Do you have an example how i can use ng2-image-lazy-load inside ionic2 app ?

Answer (score 2):

ionic-image-loader not works in ionic4+. You must create a component:

HTML

```
<ion-spinner name="dots" [hidden]="viewImage" color="primary"></ion-spinner>
<ion-img #image alt=""(ionImgDidLoad)="loadImage()" (ionError)="errorLoad()"></ion-img>
```

Typescript

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'preloader-img',
      templateUrl: './preloader-img.component.html',
      styles: [`
        ion-spinner {
          display: block;
          margin: auto;
        }
      `],
    })
    export class PreloaderImgComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      viewImage = false;

      @Input() url: string;
      @ViewChild('image', { static: false }) imageRef: IonImg;


      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.imageRef.src = this.url;
      }
      loadImage() {
        this.viewImage = true;
      }
      errorLoad() {
        this.imageRef.src = '<your_default_img>';
      }
    }
```