# How to display images only when loaded

Tags: image, angular, ionic2

Using Ionic 2 (hence Angular) I am displaying avatar images.

Images takes sometimes 1 or 2 seconds to load. While they are loading a small 'question mark' icon appears before displaying the image
[image: Demo]

How can I (in a simple way) prevent this icon to appear and display images only when fully loaded ?

Here is my code:

```
<ion-avatar item-left>
            <img [src]="user.public.avatarUrl">
          </ion-avatar>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846271/ionic-2-lazy-loading-spinner-for-pictures/38846370#38846370

Comment: Indeed... my mistake :s Thanks !